# Running Apache NiFi behind Nginx

Tags: nginx, apache-nifi, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to use nginx as reverse proxy to connect to nifi. 
I'm using the below flow: 
local machine -> http -> NGINX -> https -> Secure NiFi

Below are my nifi.properties configuration:

```
nifi.web.https.host=localhost
 nifi.web.https.port=8443
 nifi.web.https.network.interface.default=
 nifi.web.jetty.working.directory=./work/jetty
 nifi.web.jetty.threads=200
 nifi.web.max.header.size=16 KB
 nifi.web.proxy.context.path=/nifi/
 nifi.web.proxy.host=localhost:8443
 nifi.remote.input.host=localhost
 nifi.remote.input.secure=true
```

Below are my nginx configuration:

```
 server {
         listen       81;
         server_name  localhost;
     location /nifi/ {

        proxy_ssl_certificate     C:/nifi-toolkit-1.7.1/target/nifi-cert.pem;
        proxy_ssl_certificate_key C:/nifi-toolkit-1.7.1/target/nifi-key.key;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;

        proxy_pass https://localhost:8443;
        proxy_set_header X-ProxyScheme "https";
        proxy_set_header X-ProxyHost $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-ProxyPort 8443;
        proxy_set_header X-ProxyContextPath "";
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    location /nifi-api/{

        proxy_ssl_certificate     C:/nifi-toolkit-1.7.1/target/nifi-cert.pem;
        proxy_ssl_certificate_key C:/nifi-toolkit-1.7.1/target/nifi-key.key;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;

        proxy_set_header X-ProxyScheme "https";
        proxy_set_header X-ProxyHost $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-ProxyPort 443;
        proxy_set_header X-ProxyContextPath "";
        proxy_pass https://localhost:8443/nifi-api/;
 }
}
```

When I try to access nifi over nginx i get the below error in error.logs:

```
2018/09/25 15:41:55 [error] 100964#77892: *27 upstream timed out (10060: A `connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "POST /nifi-api/access/oidc/exchange HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://[::1]:8443/nifi-api/access/oidc/exchange", host: "localhost:81", referrer: "http://localhost:81/nifi/"`
```

Below are the errors I get in my browser when I hit the url :http://localhost:81/nifi/

[image: upstream timed out while calling nifi over nginx via https]

Is there any configuration settings that I am missing. Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you access NiFi without going through the proxy? That is, what happens when you try to access `https://localhost:8443/nifi` and supply the client certificate?

Comment: Hi @kevdoran, sorry for replying this late. Yes I am able to access the above url without going through nifi. It works normally. The problem arises when I'm trying to access nifi over nginx. Http is blocked  in nginx. And when I try to access any processors i get the below error

Comment: jquery.min.js:4 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://something.com/nifi/nifi/?processGroupId=root&componentIds=b3a1f15d-0165-1000-d09d-336500c5e9dd' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://something.com/nifi/nifi-api/process-groups/b3a1f15d-0165-1000-d09d-336500c5e9dd'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is nifi.web.proxy.context.path is not set properly.

check the doc:

https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDF3/HDF-3.3.0/nifi-configuration-best-practices/content/proxy_configuration.html

> NiFi will only accept HTTP requests with a X-ProxyContextPath or
>   X-Forwarded-Context header if the value is whitelisted in the
>   nifi.web.proxy.context.path property in nifi.properties. This property
>   accepts a comma separated list of expected values. In the event an
>   incoming request has an X-ProxyContextPath or X-Forwarded-Context
>   header value that is not present in the whitelist, the "An unexpected
>   error has occurred" page will be shown and an error will be written to
>   the nifi-app.log.

Answer (score 0):

As echo pointed, your X-ProxyContextPath should be the same as your location, and also the same your nifi.web.proxy.context.path= in nifi.properties.

Before attempting to introduce SSL in the mix, I like to get things running with a simple HTTP auth.

Client > http request > NGINX reverse proxy > http request > NIFI

In this case, your NIFI configuration file "nifi.properties" should look like this:

```
 nifi.web.https.host=
 nifi.web.https.port=
 nifi.web.proxy.context.path=/
 nifi.web.proxy.host=localhost:80
 nifi.remote.input.host=localhost
 nifi.remote.input.secure=false
```

Restart NIFI.

Notice the context path is / only, so that's everything under the root.

For NGINX

```
server {
         listen       80;
         server_name  localhost;
     location / {

        proxy_pass https://YOUR_NIFI_INSTANCE:8080;
        proxy_set_header X-ProxyScheme "http";
        proxy_set_header X-ProxyHost localhost;
        proxy_set_header X-ProxyPort 80;
        proxy_set_header X-ProxyContextPath "/";
    }
}
```

Update YOUR_NIFI_INSTANCE with the url of your NIFI box.